# Swift 3 - How to keep my timer counting even in background?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I want to keep going my timer even if I'm in background when HOME button is pressed. How can I do that ?

[image]

Here my working code, it's a timer for Workout. I'm using an alarm when the count is finished:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

var pickerInfo: [String] = []
var tempsCuisson:Int = 0
var timer:Timer = Timer()
var lecteur:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var estActif:Bool = false
var selection:Int?

//outlets
@IBOutlet weak var minuteurLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    minuteurLabel.text = minuteurString(temps: tempsCuisson)
}
@IBOutlet weak var activerMinuteurBtn: UIButton!



@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!


//actions
@IBAction func activerMinuteurAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    compteur()
}

@IBAction func resetMinuteurAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    resetCompteur()
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //datasource + delegate
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self

    pickerInfo = ["00.15", "00.30", "00:45",
                  "01:00", "01:15", "01:30", "01:45",
                  "02:00", "02:15", "02:30", "02:45",
                  "03:00", "03:15", "03:30", "03:45",
                  "04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45",
                  "05:00", "05:15", "05:30", "05:45",
                  "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", "06:45",
                  "07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45",
                  "08:00", "08:15", "08:30", "08:45",
                  "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00"
    ]

    activerMinuteurBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)

    activerMinuteurBtn.isEnabled = false
    activerMinuteurBtn.alpha = 0.3

    alarm()
}



func selectionCuisson(selection: Int) {

    var titreVC:String?

    switch selection {
    case 0:
        //code
        tempsCuisson = 015
        minuteurLabel.text = minuteurString(temps: tempsCuisson)
        navBar.topItem?.title = titre(str: pickerInfo[selection])
        break

    case 1:
        //code
        tempsCuisson = 030
        minuteurLabel.text = minuteurString(temps: tempsCuisson)
        navBar.topItem?.title  = titre(str: pickerInfo[selection])
        break


    case 2:
        //code
        tempsCuisson = 045
        minuteurLabel.text = minuteurString(temps: tempsCuisson)
        navBar.topItem?.title  = titre(str: pickerInfo[selection])
        break

    case 3:
        //code
        tempsCuisson = 060
        minuteurLabel.text = minuteurString(temps: tempsCuisson)
        navBar.topItem?.title  = titre(str: pickerInfo[selection])
        break
```

> all cases...

```
    default:
        //code
        print("Aucune sélection")
        break

    }

    //pour afficher option sélectionnée dans barre navigation
    //self.title = titreVC

    activerMinuteurBtn.isEnabled = true
    activerMinuteurBtn.alpha = 1
    minuteurLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

}

func minuteurString(temps: Int) -> String {
    let minutes = Int(temps) / 60 % 60
    let secondes = Int(temps) % 60

    return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes, secondes)
}

func compteur() {

    if (!estActif) {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.incrementer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
        activerMinuteurBtn.setTitle("STOP", for: UIControlState.normal)
        activerMinuteurBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: UIControlState.normal)
        estActif = true

    } else {

        timer.invalidate()
        activerMinuteurBtn.setTitle("Démarrer", for: UIControlState.normal)
        activerMinuteurBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
        estActif = false

    }


}

func incrementer() {

    if (tempsCuisson == 0) {

        timer.invalidate()
        minuteurLabel.text = "00:00"
        activerMinuteurBtn.setTitle("Démarrer", for: UIControlState.normal)
        activerMinuteurBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)

        minuteurLabel.textColor = UIColor.green

        activerMinuteurBtn.isEnabled = false
        activerMinuteurBtn.alpha = 0.3

        lecteur.play()

    } else {
        tempsCuisson -= 1
        minuteurLabel.text = minuteurString(temps: tempsCuisson)
    }

}

func resetCompteur() {
    timer.invalidate()
    tempsCuisson = 0
    minuteurLabel.text = "00:00"
    activerMinuteurBtn.setTitle("Démarrer", for: UIControlState.normal)
    activerMinuteurBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)

    estActif = false

    activerMinuteurBtn.isEnabled = false
    activerMinuteurBtn.alpha = 0.3

    pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

}

//AVAudioPlayer

func alarm() {
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let fichier = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alarm", ofType: "mp3")

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, with:[.duckOthers])
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try self.lecteur = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (URL(string: fichier!))!)
    } catch {
        print("erreur lecture ficher MP3")
        }
    }
}

//Retourner Titre

func titre(str:String) -> String {
    return str
}

//MARK - PickerViewDataSource

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


// returns the # of rows in each component..
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerInfo.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return pickerInfo[row]

}

//changer couleur pickerView label
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pickerView.frame.size.width, height: 44))
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 22)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = String(format:" %@", pickerInfo[row])

    if (row == selection) {
        label.textColor = UIColor.yellow
    }

    return label
}
//MARK - PickerViewDelegate
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    selectionCuisson(selection: row)
    selection = row
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so without going to in-depth into your code it appears that you're using a `Timer.scheduledTimer` to manually decrement the time set by the user every second.

This is not a good technique as you've found out - it only works when you know you have absolute control over the timing of your application.

Instead, what you should do is store the time when the user starts the alarm, the projected end time, and run a timer to just periodically update the UI.

(My code here isn't perfect, but it should point you in the right direction for solving the problem of keeping a timer running in the background.)

ex.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // this is pseudo-code as I don't have my compiler open :(
    let start: Date!
    let end: Date!

    func selectionCuisson(selection: Int) {

         ...

         start = Date()
         end = Date(timeInterval: tempsCuisson, since: start)
    }

 }
```

Then you create a timer that will just update the UI.

```
// You can set this to be faster than the increment, for a smoother UI experience
// put in compteur()? I think
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.incrementer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
timer.fire()

...

func incrementer() {
    let tempsCuisson = end - start
    if tempsCuisson < 0 {
        // End your Timing Function here
        timer.invalidate()
        ...
        lecteur.play()
    } else {
        minuteurLabel.text = minuteurString(temps: tempsCuisson)
    }
}
```

You can also set a Local Notification to go off when the app goes into the background using the `end` date

```
// when the app becomes inactive
let notification = UILocalNotification()
...
notification.fireDate = end
UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: Hi @Stephen, thanks for your answer. Where am I supposed to declare that code ?

let start = Date() 
let end = Date(timeInterval: tempsCuisson, since: start)

Comment: Thank you very much @Stephen for your update, last question is about 'let tempsCuisson = end - start' it's not working. I got error: "Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'Date!' operands" How to fix it please ?

Comment: I never used notification before, where am I supposed to use it in my code ? // when the app becomes inactive
let notification = UILocalNotification()
...
notification.fireDate = end
UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

Comment: I tried to this that : var tempsCuisson = end.timeIntervalSince1970 - start.timeIntervalSince1970 but It seems not working... by the way, all the app is currently not working now... timer is static...

Comment: sorry about not ever replying.  Glad this worked out for you in the end.